# Oracle Function to Get Last Updated Timestamps For All Tables In A Schema

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've written the following function:

```
declare
    v_count DATE;
    strsql VARCHAR2(200);
begin

    for r in (select OBJECT_NAME from all_objects where OBJECT_TYPE='TABLE' 
    and OWNER='SALES' 
    and OBJECT_NAME LIKE 'T%' 
    ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME DESC) 
    loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.OBJECT_NAME);
        strsql := 'select SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(MAX(ORA_ROWSCN)) FROM : 1 INTO v_count';
        execute immediate strsql USING r.OBJECT_NAME;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_count);
    end loop;

end;
```

Unfortunately, two (bad) things are happening:

1. It outputs only the first OBJECT_NAME (the first PUT_LINE).
2. It does NOT execute the second PUT_LINE.

Obviously, I am NOT a Oracle developer, I just need a quick and dirty function to show me the last updated times for all tables in a given schema.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: By updated, does the LAST_DDL_TIME in all objects give you the right information?

Comment: LAST_DDL_TIME, by the docs, is when the table is last modified via a DDL command (including Grants/Revokes).  I need last insert/update/delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of work, breakage, consulting the almigty Google, I came up with this function:

```
declare
    v_count TIMESTAMP;
    strsql VARCHAR2(200);
    tblname VARCHAR2(32);
begin

    for r in (select OBJECT_NAME from all_objects where OBJECT_TYPE='TABLE' 
    and OWNER='SALES' 
    and OBJECT_NAME LIKE 'T%' 
    ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME) 
    loop
      begin
        tblname := R.OBJECT_NAME;
        strsql := 'select SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(MAX(ORA_ROWSCN)) FROM SALES.' || tblname;
        execute immediate strsql into v_count;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tblname || ' ' || v_count);
        EXCEPTION
        when others then 
          null;
         end; 
    end loop;
end;
```

The ORA_ROWSCN is held for a limited amount of time, so if it isn't there an exception will be thrown. If I wrote this "correctly", it would only return a null for ORA-006550, and I would figure out a way to sort the results by the SCN (but descending).

Answer (score 1):

Your strsql contains incorrect SQL which cannot be executed. So, first `execute immediate` raises an exception (sure you saw it).

Table name cannot be used from parameter. You should something like

```
strsql := 'select .... from ' || r.owner || '.' || r.object_name;
```

Comment: Yes, I saw it (even though it took me a bit to see what I was looking for). Unfortunately, it seems that information is only retained for a relatively short time, so if I run into a table that hasn't been modified a SQL error is raised.

Comment: Also, your point on qualifying the table name with the owner is taken, it just happens to work for me because some synomyms exist.

Comment: @Jason - also your `into` clause needs to be in the `execute immediate`, not part of the string; and you won't have a `using` clause any more, since the object name can't be bound. But as you've discovered, you can't rely on ora_rowscn for what you're trying to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the date type of v_count to timestamp and select clause in strsql to the following.

```
SQL>      declare
  2           v_count timestamp;
  3           strsql VARCHAR2(200);
  4       begin
  5
  6           for r in (select OBJECT_NAME from all_objects
  7          where OBJECT_TYPE='TABLE'
  8           and OWNER='SCOTT'
  9           and OBJECT_NAME like'T%'
 10           )
 11           loop
 12               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.OBJECT_NAME);
 13               strsql := 'select SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(MAX(ORA_ROWSCN)) FROM '||r.OBJECT_NAME || ' ';
 14               execute immediate strsql into v_count;
 15                 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_count);
 16           end loop;
 17
 18       end;
 19       /
TESTEMP
21-APR-15 11.52.20.000000 AM
TESTEMP2
20-APR-15 09.53.12.000000 PM
TEST_AUDIT
21-APR-15 11.52.20.000000 AM

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```